# MYSQL Table Reset Auto Increment to 1, while retaining existing records with ids

Tags: mysql, autoincrement

I have a MySQL table naming Product for a classified site, product_id is bigint(20) AUTO_INCREMENT field.

Currently AUTO_INCREMENT value is 224143.

Client want it to restart from 1. 
but this table has 7000 existing STARTING from prduct_id 210235 to 224143.
User can manage their items by using its id, i can not revise, regenerate ids, but want to restart next AUTOINCREMENT ENTRY from 1, and hold the existing record as it is.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  MySQL will automatically set the auto_increment value to `MAX(column)+1` even if you've used `alter table tbl auto_increment = 1`.  And that's a restriction with a very valid rationale -- duplicating keys never ends well.

Comment: yes, i already try to update last Auto increment value, as you said it take max+1. OK i am leaving it as it is, As if restarted, soon there will be clash when MAX+1 will be equal to existing ID(This may not occurs as i will delete existing data after 1 year.), But i have another thing in mind INTEGER WRAPAROUND After reaching Max value there would be overflow, do you know the behavior of mysql (Whether it will generate next ID to -ve or restart from 1 IN-CASE of Reaching maximum value)? (SORRY for writing as a blog)

Comment: Ask new questions in new questions, not as comments to existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think this is a terrible idea and you are only asking for trouble if you do this.

Second, I am not sure it is at all possible to restart the `auto_increment` counter back to 1, as MySQL will prevent it for good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet to get the behavior you want would be to export the data to a file (mysql -Bse "select * from table" will export tab separated by default) and import the data into a new table, either rewrite the ID number using awk/perl or re-import the data without the ID column and let it auto_increment from 1 on the new table.  Be advised you will have to fix any relationships that other tables have to the ID number of this table.

Answer (score 0):

I understood what you want to do. You need to retain records starting from id 210235 and before that want to insert new records starting from id 1 and after insertion again reset the id to max value, this can be achieved by update statements as below:-

first get the max value into a variable maxvalue and then:-

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

UPDATE table SET id = (id - maxvalue) WHERE report_id >= maxvalue

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;